# How to drill down in the following NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I  am getting the following NSDictionary for each cell of my UiTableView. I have to be able to drill down and get the first id value in the assets sub structure below.

```
{
    assets =     (
                {
            "chunk_size" = 262144;
            file =             {
                "is_dirty" = 0;
                "mongo_grid_f_s_file" =                 {
                    file =                     {
                        "_id" =                         {
                            "$id" = 503a58e09b41648f69000001;
                        };
                        chunkSize = 262144;
                        filename = "/private/var/tmp/phpPPZsUf";
                        length = 5849;
                        md5 = 5f2700f4d953ef866fe1d4967f9965fb;
                        name = Image1;
                        uploadDate =                         {
                            sec = 1346001120;
                            usec = 819000;
                        };
                    };
                    gridfs =                     {
                        chunks =                         {
                            w = 1;
                            wtimeout = 10000;
                        };
                        "chunks_name" = "assets.chunks";
                        "files_name" = "assets.files";
                        w = 1;
                        wtimeout = 10000;
                    };
                };
            };
            id = 503a58e09b41648f69000001;
            length = 5849;
            md5 = 5f2700f4d953ef866fe1d4967f9965fb;
            name = Image1;
            "upload_date" = "0.81900000 1346001120";
        },
                {
            "chunk_size" = 262144;
            file =             {
                "is_dirty" = 0;
                "mongo_grid_f_s_file" =                 {
                    file =                     {
                        "_id" =                         {
                            "$id" = 503a58e09b41648f69000004;
                        };
                        chunkSize = 262144;
                        filename = "/private/var/tmp/phphxvI3H";
                        length = 1551;
                        md5 = f193ffe87eb0138608a206dcf72bf704;
                        name = Image2;
                        uploadDate =                         {
                            sec = 1346001120;
                            usec = 841000;
                        };
                    };
                    gridfs =                     {
                        chunks =                         {
                            w = 1;
                            wtimeout = 10000;
                        };
                        "chunks_name" = "assets.chunks";
                        "files_name" = "assets.files";
                        w = 1;
                        wtimeout = 10000;
                    };
                };
            };
            id = 503a58e09b41648f69000004;
            length = 1551;
            md5 = f193ffe87eb0138608a206dcf72bf704;
            name = Image2;
            "upload_date" = "0.84100000 1346001120";
        }
    );
    coordinates =     {
        latitude = "37.78584";
        longitude = "-122.4064";
    };
    "created_at" = "2012-08-26T12:12:00-0500";
    id = 503a58e09b4164cf5a00000a;
    "number_of_cars" = 1;

}
```

I have tried the following:

```
 NSDictionary * classifiedAssets = [classified objectForKey:@"assets"];
```

Then to get each id, I have done:

```
[classifiedImages objectForKey:@"id"]
```

However all I am getting is:

```
(503a58e09b41648f69000001, 503a58e09b41648f69000004)
```

I was hoping to get back an NSArray of the various IDs and not a parenthesis comma delimited list.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may already have what you need; and here's the explanation:

```
NSDictionary * classifiedAssets = [classified objectForKey:@"assets"];
```

Is not exactly what you'd expect: you may *think* it's an NSDictionary (due to your typing of the variable), but it's actually an NSArray (due to the parenthesis in the JSON instead of curly braces). Then this:

```
[classifiedImages objectForKey:@"id"]
// by which I *assume* you mean:
[classifiedAssets valueForKey:@"id"]
```

Is actually taking advantage of a nifty feature of NSArrays: calling `valueForKey:` on an NSArray gives you an NSArray of the results of calling `valueForKey:` on each member.

I assume you are talking about the parens and commas in an NSLog line. In that context, a comma-delimited set of things surrounded by parenthesis *indicates* an NSArray (try logging it's `class` and see)

Comment: sorry for the newbie question but how do you log a class?

Comment: Actually, you cannot call `objectForKey` on arrays. What you probably mean is `valueForKey`

Comment: @jini `NSLog(@"%@", [someObj class]);`

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of your asset ids, you could do something like this:

```
// Assuming that 'classified' is the dictionary you have posted
NSArray *ids = [classified valueForKeyPath:@"assets.id"];
```

Now, what's interesting about `valueForKeyPath` is that let's you drill down your objects via dot notation while calling `valueForKey` for every object if encounters an `NSArray`

Comment: [classified valueForKeyPath:@"assets.id"] still gets me (
    503a58e09b41648f69000001,
    503a58e09b41648f69000004
)

Comment: This is what you've asked for... an `NSArray` with the ids :) (You got it correct in the first place as @ctrahey suggested. I just wanted to point out a more convenient/streamlined way of doing it)